# Does the Intel Haswell NUC built in SATA port support port multiplier technology?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

With SATA port multiplier technology it is possible to connect more than one drive to a single SATA port.

The new (end 2013) Intel Haswell NUC models, like DN2810FYK, D34010WYK or D54250WYK, have a SATA port on the motherboard.

Does this Intel Haswell NUC built in SATA port support port multiplier technology?

Comment: Have you tried if it works under Linux? It's the DH82Q87 controller. (Q87)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Mikael Neither does Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 Linux detect any of the drives behind a port multiplier when more than 1 drive is attached to the port multiplier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have connected a Dawicontrol DC-6510 PM (Sil3726 chipset) to the SATA port of a D54250WYK NUC. I have updated the D54250WYK its BIOS version from factory 0018 to 0022. I connected two 2.5" drives to the port multiplier and the port multiplier to the NUC.

The result is that the drives behind the port multiplier could **not** be detected by a 64-bit Windows 8.1 Pro OS, in other words Intel Haswell NUC's do not support SATA port multiplier technology. After removing the port multiplier, and connecting that drive directly to the motherboard SATA connector, the drive was correctly identified by the Windows OS.

#### Note #1: attaching only 1 drive succeeds

When attaching only 1 drive to the port multiplier allows the Haswell NUC to boot from it. But attaching only 1 drive defeats the purpose of a port multiplies, which is connecting multiple drives to one SATA port.

#### Update #2: tested with Ubuntu 13.10 Linux

I have repeated this test by connecting two 3.5" drives behind the same Dawicontrol DC-6510 PM and attaching that port multiplier to the blue SATA of the D54250WYK. Neither the BIOS of the NUC nor the Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 installer is able to detect any of the two drives that are connected to the port multiplier.

#### Conclusion

This leads to the conclusion that the Intel Haswell NUC built in SATA port **does not support port multiplier technology**.